# Given heaps $h$ and $h'$, is true that if $h \leq h'$ and $h' \leq h$, then $h = h'$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We can define that a heap (or multiset, if you prefer) with elements taken from a set $X$ is a function $h : H \rightarrow X$. Given heaps $h,h' : H,H' \rightarrow X,$ define that $h \leq h'$ iff there is an injection $i : H \rightarrow H'$ making the obvious diagram commute; further, we can override the usual equality relation by asserting that $h = h'$ iff there's an isomorphism $i : H \rightarrow H'$ making the obvious diagram commute.

Is it true that if $h \leq h'$ and $h' \leq h$, then $h = h'$?

See at first I thought it was a straightforward application of [CBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), but there seems to be no guarantee that any of the necessarily-existing bijections will actually make the diagram commute.

Comment: This is not category theory, this is elementary set-theory. The answer is Yes if you require the maps $H \to X$ to be injective, otherwise No.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, wait the answer is no? There must be an obvious counterexample that I've missed...

Comment: Something to keep in mind: CBS can also mean "Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main observation is that a "heap" $H \to X$ can be interpreted as an $X$-indexed family of sets by taking the fibres of the map. (In fact, the category $\mathbf{Set}_{/ X}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^X$.) So just apply the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem componentwise.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Is there a categorial definition of the transform $f \mapsto g$ satisfying $g(y) = \{x \mid f(x) = y\}$? It seems very similar to the contravariant powerset functor.

Comment: No. This is something very special to $\mathbf{Set}$, and the inverse operation requires the axiom of replacement.